# Problems css height and positioning of text fields in form

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with a textarea and submitbuttons in my form.

Here's a first screenshot of a seemingly normal situation:

[image]

And here's what happens if I set the textarea to have 30 columns:

[image]

The textarea just went right over the buttons. I'd expect the buttons to be pushed down. Or anything below it, for that matter. What do I need to set to make this happen?

Comment: you'll need to include your html/css to get an answer on this one.

Comment: At first, you need to provide a sample of your html/css code.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely (*and you should show more CSS code to be sure*) you have your labels/fields floated inside an element with fixed height..

Use an element with `clear:both` after the textarea..